# Import Module not found even though it is in path

Tags: svn, powershell, jenkins

My PowerShell modules are not loading in certain environments even though they are in the path and the script executes successfully manually.

eg.My powershell script has the following contents:

```
Write-Host $env:PSModulePath
Import-Module SSH-Sessions
```

The SSH-Sessions module has been put in the PSModulePath in `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\SSH-Sessions`. It is executed with the command `powershell .\folder\test.ps1`.

The output of the script's  first line shows the module path is: `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\`

When executed in a command prompt all works as expected, but as a subversion post-commit hook or as a Jenkins build step this fails with the following errors:

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'SSH-Sessions' was not loaded because no 
valid module file was found in any module directory.

At C:\path\to\workspace\folder\test.ps1
:2 char:14
+ Import-Module <<<<  SSH-Sessions
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (SSH-Sessions:String) [Impo 
   rt-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm 
   ands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Why can Powershell not find the module?

Comment: First of all, you don't have write access to that directory. Could it be that the PowerShell instance that cannot load the module is run by another user and the `SSH-Sessions` folder only exists in `$Env:LocalAppData\VirtualStore` of your current user?

Comment: When the script runs in a subversion hook, does it give any output from `Write-Host $env:PSModulePath`? A subversion hook starts with an empty environment, not even `%PATH%` is set.

Comment: Keep in mind on a 64-bit OS there are two such directories c:\windows\system32\windowsPowershell\v1.0\modules and c:\windows\syswow64\windowsPowershell\v1.0\modules.  The one used depends on the bitness of the hosting application - usually -  depending on how the hosting app is invoking powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the line `[Environment]::UserName` to the script confirms the Jenkins build step is run by SYSTEM user, which has no read rights in the `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules` folder.

**Solution**: Create a `C:\PowerShellModules` folder and add it to the **system** variable `PSModulePath`

SYSTEM user has full control over the folder.